# Relative Condition number of composite function

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, condition-number

I want to find a function $$h = g \circ f$$ such that condition number of $g$ and $f$ are greater than $10$, but the condition number of $h$ is less than $1$.

I am trying to use polynomials like $x^{10}$ for $f$ and $g$, but I find that the condition number of $h$ can't be less than $1$.
If I fix the condition number of $h$ to be less than $1$ and the condition number of $f$ to be greater than $10$, then I find that the condition number of $g$ must be less than $1$.

Comment: Very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4045742/307944
However, that question allows for arbitrary vector spaces whereas the notation of this question suggests that the vector spaces are just $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the condition number of a composition is the *product* of the condition numbers. Specifically, if $x \not =0$ and $h(x) \not = 0$, then the relative condition number of the function $h$ at the point $x$ is given by
$$ \kappa_h(x) = \left | \frac{xh'(x)}{h(x)} \right|.$$
Now if $h = f \circ g$ and the chain rule can be applied, then
$$ \frac{xh'(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{x f(g(x))g'(x)}{f(g(x))} = \frac{y f'(y)}{f(y)}\frac{x g'(x)}{g(x)}$$
where $y = g(x)$ and we assume that $y \not = 0$. It follows that
$$\kappa_h(x) = \kappa_f(g(x)) \kappa_g(x).$$
In particular, if $\kappa_f(g(x)) \ge 10$ and $\kappa_g(x) \ge 10$, then $\kappa_h(x) \ge 100$ is inevitable.

Comment: κh(x) is at most κf(g(x))κg(x). Hence, Kh(x) is always less than or equal to 100 given kg and kf is 10. Condition number is sup of changes in input.

Comment: @AmarAgnihotri No, you are mistaken. The correct abstract definition of the condition number is more involved than you suggest. I use a formula that is correct when the function is differentiable with a continuous derivative.